# Loading "custom resources" in Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: php, zend-framework, resources

Everything was working fine in 1.9.6. I changed to 1.10 and now I have a lot of Warning for basically every Application Resource.

It looks like the ZF is looking for Application Resources in the "custom resources" path that I set up from: pluginpaths.App_Application_Resource = "App/Application/Resource. 
Is there any way to avoid this!? (Thank you in advance for your time)

```
application.ini:

resources.locale.default = sq_AL
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0

; VIEW & HTML Markup Options
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.language = "en"
resources.view.setSeparator=" - "
resources.view.helperPath.View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.view[] = 

; custom resources
**pluginpaths.App_Application_Resource = "App/Application/Resource"**
```

at library/App/Application/Resource/Cache I have a class "App_Application_Resource_Cache extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract" that I need for the cache.
The problem is that now on the first page I have a lot of warnings like:

```
Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/App/Application/Resource/Locale.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php  on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib64/php/modules/App/Application/Resource/Locale.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/App/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib64/php/modules/App/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/App/Application/Resource/Layout.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib64/php/modules/App/Application/Resource/Layout.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/./views/helpers/Doctype.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib64/php/modules/./views/helpers/Doctype.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/./views/helpers/HeadMeta.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib64/php/modules/./views/helpers/HeadMeta.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/./views/helpers/HeadTitle.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/home//httpdocs:/tmp:/var/home/) in /var/home//library/Zend/Loader.php on line 190
```

Just in case someone needs it, at the bootstrap this is the Autoload-er

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
 protected function _initAutoload()
    {
  $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
   array(
          'namespace' => 'App',
          'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
      )
     );
     return $autoloader;
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to download and update the ZF, PEAR?

Comment: And can you add which directory your application actually resides in?

Comment: @Pekka, I downloaded ZF files from the framework.zend.com webpage. 

The dir structure:
|-- application
|   |-- configs
|   |-- controllers
|   |-- layouts
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|-- cache
|-- httpdocs
*
|-- library
|   |-- App
|   |-- Zend
|   `-- ZendX





ibrary/App/
`-- Application
    `-- Resource


there is some problem with the editor here as I see. 
The Zend framework is located under library/

Comment: All right, but where did you download them to? Look at the error messages, it is complaining about the framework being located in an entirely different directory than your application. Or is there another installation of the Framework interfering with your autoloading process?

Comment: @Pekka , 
I have corrected my previous post while you re-asked the question :)

I downloaded the Zend files under the library/ folder

\n\r php.ini has /usr/share/php/ in the include path and I just noticed that the autoloader is looking under:

/usr/share/php/App/Application/Resource/Locale.php

Comment: You are not allowed to access that path from your PHP script, look at the error message (/usr/share is not in the list of allowed directories). Can you change the include path to (I guess) `/var/home/library/Zend/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this question got sorted in the comments :) Making this into an answer you can accept to close the question.

You are not allowed to access that path from your PHP script, look at the error message (/usr/share is not in the list of allowed directories). Changing the include path to (I guess) /`var/home/library/Zend/` should solve it.

> Apparently there is a problem with PLESK & CentOS where the include path of PHP is not accessible from the vhosts!

I think this is down to the `open_basedir` setting that forbids the virtual hosts to access anything outside them, it's not OS specific. Anyway, glad it got sorted!

Answer (score 7):

@Pekka

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    //get_include_path(),
)));
```

By commenting out the `get_include/path()`  (in index.php) I have ommitted the include from /usr/share/php/. Warnings are gone.

Thank you for your (superb) assistance!

Apparently there is a problem with PLESK & CentOS where the include path of PHP is not accessible from the vhosts!

Comment: Yep, I _just_ experienced this very same headache and that solved it for me too!

Comment: Yes this solution worked for my in an zend app created in the cloud with https://phpfog.com/